# Erro ao sincronizar grandle com biblioteca de mascara para campos

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle

Estou tentando instalar uma dependencia para mascara de campos porém ao adiconar ela, tenho problemas, no log aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(@string/app_name) from AndroidManifest.xml:39:9-41
>       is also present at [br.com.jansenfelipe:androidmask:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:11:9-36 value=(AndroidMask).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:35:5-170:19 to override.

a biblioteca é esta:

https://github.com/jansenfelipe/androidmask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ocorre o seguinte:

A biblioteca acima utiliza esta mesma `Tag Label`!

Para corrigir é necessário especificar no `AndroidManifest` qual será utilizado pela sua aplicação, conforme sugerido no erro:

> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:35:5-170:19 to override.

Segue um exemplo:

```
  <application xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:replace="android:label" 
  ...
  >

 </application>
```